# Best way to call wasm module functions in AudioWorkletProcessor?

Tags: angular, web-audio-api, webassembly, audio-worklet

I am using Angular for development of a video conferencing web application. I am trying to call some wasm functions in my `AudioWorkletProcessor` class. However, I am quite stuck on how to pass the wasm module into the `AudioWorkletProcessor` and then call those functions. I was able to instantiate the wasm module from the js file generated from emcc (using command: `emcc test.cpp -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1`) and then tried passing this module through the `options.processorOptions` parameter when we construct the `AudioWorkletNode`; however, it seems like Function objects cannot be passed as it gives a `DataCloneError`. Is there a better way of instantiating the wasm module and passing it into the worklet processor so that I can use its functions?

Code of audio.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AudioContext, AudioWorkletNode } from 'standardized-audio-context';
import * as Module from '../../../assets/worklet/a.out.js'; // a.out.js is file generated by emcc
declare const WebAssembly: any;

@Injectable()
export class AudioService {
  audioCtx = new AudioContext();

  constructor() {}

  async createNewSetting(track) {
    const srcNode = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamTrackSource(track);
    const destNode = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();

    await this.audioCtx.resume();
    await this.audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule(
      './assets/worklet/spatial-processor.js'
    );

    // Instantiate the wasm module and put in path to file
    const wasm = await Module({ locateFile: function(s) { return 'assets/worklet/' + s; }});
    
    // Will throw DataCloneError
    const spatialNode = new AudioWorkletNode(
      this.audioCtx,
      'spatial-processor',
      { processorOptions: {
        compiledModule: wasm
      }}
    );

    // Connect the nodes
    srcNode.connect(spatialNode);
    spatialNode.connect(destNode);

    // Return the updated audio stream
    return destNode.stream.getTracks()[0];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing an instantiated WASM module to a worker (or an AudioWorklet) isn't possible. It only works when the WASM module is compiled but not yet instantiated. There is an example on MDN which shows how to do that with a regular worker but it works the same way when using the `processorOptions` of an `AudioWorkletProcessor`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Module#sending_a_compiled_module_to_a_worker

The idea is to use `compileStreaming()` on the main thread and `instantiate()` in the worker.

On the other hand it's also possible to import everything directly into an AudioWorklet as shown in this example. However, I would not recommend doing that since compiling the code on the audio thread may result in an audible glitch.

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/design-pattern/wasm/

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. When I do the compileStreaming() method and instantiate() in the worker, I get a 'Import #0 module="wasi_snapshot_preview1" error: module is not an object or function' error. I know that the js file that emcc produces fills in the functions in this missing module, but since I cannot use the js file in the processor, do I have to fill in the missing module methods myself (through the import object which is passed into instantiate()), or is there a more feasible way of approaching this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. As far as I know it's not so easy with emscripten because it produces some glue code (the a.out.js file) which calls those functions for you. Does that help?

Comment: Yea that helps.